# How to change quantum in xv6?

Tags: operating-system, xv6

I need to change the quantum amount for xv6 OS, so that each process, instead of running in only one clock tick, runs for k clock ticks which k is hardcoded into the xv6.
Now, I have viewed the trap.c file and I understand that each time when yield() is called, the program must give up the CPU and its time for the next program (in the round-robin algorithm). But I don't understand how to change quantum value.

Comment: Why is this tagged linux?

Comment: @stark Because those who know linux probably have dealt with xv6 either.

Comment: I have to ask....why?

Comment: @Mathieu Yeah, thanks.